# Stopping a recursive generator & permutations

Tags: python, exception, recursion, generator, permutation

As an exercise, I've been trying out various ways of generating all permutations of a list in Python -- recursive, non-recursive... -- and comparing the performance with `itertools.permutations()`. But I'm having trouble with the generator version of the recursive method, which doesn't finish cleanly with a `StopIteration` exception, but instead throws an `IndexError`:

```
def spawnperms(alist):
    """same algorithm as recursive option, but a generator"""
    if (alist == []):
        yield []
    for perm in spawnperms(alist[:-1]):
        for i in range(len(perm)+1):
            yield perm[:i] + [alist[-1]] + perm[i:]
```

Calling this from the Python interpreter:

```
>>> for i in spawnperms(range(3)):
...     print i
... 
[2, 1, 0]
[1, 2, 0]
[1, 0, 2]
[2, 0, 1]
[0, 2, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in spawnperms
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in spawnperms
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in spawnperms
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in spawnperms
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Ouch. I tried stepping through it with `pdb`, which nearly created a stack overflow in my brain, but what I understood is that the recursion "reaches down" to the empty list, and then the outer (I think) `for` loop runs out of indices.

How can I correct my code?

**EDIT:** One learning from Mark Byers' deceptively simple correct answer is that ***clean coding practices can prevent mistakes***. Had I used an `else` systematically after `if`, regardless of whether I thought the condition could ever be revisited, this wouldn't have happened. And it still feels very stupid!

Comment: To test whether a list is empty, `if not alist:` is enough.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. I'd normally do that, but was focussed on something else. You're entirely right, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing an `else`:

```
if (alist == []):
    yield []
else:
    for ...
```

This is because `yield` does not behave in the same way as `return`. Execution continues after the `yield`  statement when you request the next value.

Comment: Hmmmmmm... the difference between `yield` and `return` is precisely why I thought I didn't need the `else`. But I think my logic is flawed.

Comment: :) yes, my logic was entirely flawed. Many thanks -- how stupid I feel now.